# Using a DSM and DEM together to identify height above ground

Tags: dem, srtm, aster

A pretty basic question I feel, but its something I thought I understood and further reading has caused more confusion.

DEM is the topographical/elevation of the ground. DTM and DSM are pretty much similar and will include height values such as trees buildings etc.

In work, I am currently using ASTER to convert altitude from an Android API to height above ground using ASTER (as in most literature its an elevation model).

However, looking at some research papers, some people have tried to use ASTER along with other DEM [to try to estimate building heights](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/12/2008/htm).

So, I'm just wondering, is it possible to use ASTER (or other DEMs to estimate height above ground) and then use DSM/DTM projects (AW3D30, etc.) to estimate building heights and use the two in the same project (map 3D points *within* a building?)

Comment: Your title doesn't correspond to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have since tried to change the title to better suit the question. If you have any advice on this topic, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try for something shorter, as a topical statement (not a question), like "Using a DSM and DEM together to identify height above ground"

Comment: Assuming your DSM and DTM are LiDAR data you will most likely have a vertical datum issue to deal with.  In the USA most LiDAR reference NAVD88 but the ASTER surface references WGS84/EGM96.   See here for more details:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090447917300084